# Как быстро и удобно обрабатывать большие массивы?

Tags: javascript, node.js

обход массивов рекомендован через

```
for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    console.log(ar[i]);
}
```

но данный подход не предусматривает дырки в массиве.

если в массиве есть удаленные элементы, есть такое способ обработки:

```
for(var o of ar) {
    console.log(o);
}
```

но скорость обработки падает

у меня на 1 000 000 записей разница в методах дала 20 кратное замедление обработки

```js
var ar = new Array(1000000);
ar.fill(1);

console.time();
for(var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
  ar[i] = 2;
  
}                             
console.timeEnd();

console.time();
for(var o of ar) {
  o = 2;
  
}                             
console.timeEnd();
```

может есть третий способ дающий хорошую скорость и необходимую гибкость в обработке больших массивов?

`UPDATE`

предложенный `Леша Марченковский` вариант, дает хороший прирост скорости на дырявых массивах:

```js
var br = new Array(10000000);
for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
  var l = parseInt(Math.random() * 1000000);
  br[i] = 1;
}

console.time();
for(var i = 0; i < br.length; i++) {
  if(br[i] == undefined) continue;
  br[i] = 2;
}
console.timeEnd();

console.time();
for(var o of br) {  
  o = 2;
}
console.timeEnd();
```

> default: 1365.980ms
>
> default: 6656.250ms

Comment: все методы в массиве, такие как forEach,map и т.д. пропускают дырки. Их производительность зависит от реализации в браузере

Comment: вообще такие замеры дело неблагодарное. Никогда не можешь быть уверенным, что именно ты измерил. И будет ли этот тест показывать нужные данные, а не просто будет выкинут, как ничего не делающий. Например в FF результаты замеров отличаются меньше чем на миллисекунду.

Comment: У меня обработался миллион записей за 70 мс во втором случае (и за 30 в первом). Это величина, сравнимая с погрешностью времени выполнения HTTP-запроса. У вас действительно настолько большие данные, что разница становится заметной?

Comment: @Grundy, а на nodeJS?  ИМХО: forEach и map создают лишнии сущности -> расход памяти

Comment: @etki, у меня 6мс против 125мс

Comment: @ravend, все зависит от конкретной реализации.

Comment: @ravend, в чем выражается дырявость массива в коде в вопросе? (до обновления)

Comment: @Grundy, в первом варианте дырок нет, но подход учитывающий такую возможность. Не стал сразу загромождать вопрос кучей вариантов.

Comment: @ravend, для какого environment ты хочешь проверить? В разных браузерах показывает разные времена, например в FF результаты почти не отличаются. В разных версиях ноды результаты так же могут отличаться

Comment: @Grundy, больше интересует nodeJS. Вариант с for in/of явно не быстрее классического for. Но удобней в работе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53257/discussion-between-grundy-and-ravend).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обрабатывать так называемые "дырки", используйте конструкцию

```
if (i in arr) {}
```

Comment: этого не достаточно, значение `undefined` Не гарантирует наличие дырки. Наличие дырки гарантирует отсутствие соответствующего числового ключа.

Comment: да, этот код будет некорректно работать в случае значений undefined в самих элементах массива. Но для достижения нужного результата можно заменить undefined на что-то типа null

Comment: Вместо строгой проверки на undefined и на null можно использовать нестрогую на null.

Comment: Нет нельзя, потому что в этом случае будет некорректный результат для других значений

Comment: @Grundy Каких? Нестрогий null срабатывает только с null и undefined же.

Comment: Тогда `if (i in arr)`

Comment: @Arnial, `[undefined,null]` - вот массив в котором нет дырок

Comment: лучше не `in` который смотрит так же и в прототипе, а `hasOwnProperty` который смотрит только в текущем объекте. Хотя для массива разница может отсутствовать